# Why is my JavaScript code not functioning after using Browserify?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, browserify

I realized that I wrote my JS code using node modules when I want it to be in browser, so I did the command browserify main.js -o bundle.js and replaced the source link for main.js with bundle.js. Now maps that I made using Plotly aren't appearing even though they were before and things I used using node modules still aren't working. Although I no longer get the error 'require is not defined.' Attached is an image of the new errors I'm getting.

index.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <h1>Find the nearest subway station to an address!</h1>
       
        <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/opencage-api-client@0.3.0/dist/opencage-api.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        <style>
            body, div{
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="loadMap();">
        <div id="map"></div>
        <div id='pie'></div>
        <p>Find the closest subway station to an address!</p>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="addressInput"></input>
            <button type='button' onclick="getNearestStation()">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <form action="action.php" method="POST">
            <label><br><br><br> Name: 
             <input type="text" name="Name" class="Input" style="width: 225px" required>
            </label>
            <br>
            <label> Suggestions for new features: <br>
             <textarea name="Comment" class="Input" style="width: 300px" required></textarea>
            </label>
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit Comment" class="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js
`

```
var avgLat = 0;
var avgLon = 0;
var lat = [];
var lon = [];
var text = [];
var data = a dictionary with a lot of data


function loadMap() {
    Plotly.setPlotConfig({mapboxAccessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYnlyb25nYSIsImEiOiJjanA0bHVvaDkwdWJ2M3NvYjRzOWF2bTEzIn0.uX3J1gjBrSq6ofv8BUNkWw'});
    Plotly.plot('map', setupMapData(data), setupMapLayout(data)); 
    Plotly.plot('pie', piedata)
}


function setupMapData(rawdata) {
        for (var arr of rawdata['data']) {
                coords = arr[11].split("(")[1].split(" ")
                lonNum = Number(coords[0])
                latNum = Number(coords[1].replace(")",""))
                text.push(arr[10])
                lat.push(Number(latNum))
                lon.push(Number(lonNum))
        }
        return  [{"type":"scattermapbox",
             "mode":"markers",
             "marker":{"size":5, "color":"rgb(230, 0, 0)"},
             "lat":lat,
             "lon":lon,
             "text":text}];
}


function findCenter(arr) {
    maxLat = Math.max.apply(null, lat) 
    minLat = Math.min.apply(null, lat);
    maxLon = Math.max.apply(null, lon);
    minLon = Math.min.apply(null, lon);
    avgLat = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
    avgLon = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;
}



function setupMapLayout(arr) {
    findCenter()
    return {
            "mapbox": {
                "style":"streets",
                "zoom":11,
                "center":{
                        "lat":avgLat, 
                        "lon":avgLon
                        }
                      }
            };
}

setupMapData(data)
setupMapLayout(data)

var percentNorth = 0;
var percentSouth = 0;
var directCount = 0;
var moreNorth = 0;
var moreSouth = 0;
for (item of lat) {
  if (item > 40.7132751) {
    moreNorth += 1
    directCount += 1
  } else {
    moreSouth += 1
    directCount += 1
  }
}
percentNorth = moreNorth / directCount * 100
percentSouth = moreSouth / directCount * 100
var piedata = [{
  values: [percentNorth, percentSouth],
  labels: ['Percent of Stations North of My House', 'Percent of Stations South of My House'],
  type: 'pie'
}];


var NodeGeocoder = require('node-geocoder');
let geolib = require('geolib');

var geocoder = NodeGeocoder({
  provider: 'opencage',
  apiKey: my api key
});

function getNearestStation() {
  var addressInput = document.getElementById('addressInput').value
  geocoder.geocode({address: addressInput, limit: 1}, function(err, res) {
    var geoLat = res[0]['latitude']
    var geoLon = res[0]['longitude']
    addressCoord = {latitude: geoLat, longitude: geoLon}
    counter = 0
    coordList = {}
    for (item of lat) {
      coordList[text[counter]] = {latitude: item, longitude: lon[counter]}
      counter += 1
    }
    var distances = []
    orderDistance =  geolib.orderByDistance(addressCoord, coordList)
    for (dict of orderDistance) {
        distances.push(dict['distance'])
    }
    var distance = Math.min(...distances)
    var place = ""
    for (dict of orderDistance) {
      if (dict['distance'] == distance) {
        place = dict['key']
      }
    }
    alert("The nearest subway station is " + Math.min(...distances) + " meters away at " + place)
  });
}
```

`

The part of bundle.js producing an error

```
    `computeDestinationPoint: function(start, distance, bearing, radius) {

        var lat = this.latitude(start);
        var lng = this.longitude(start);

        radius = (typeof radius === 'undefined') ? this.radius : Number(radius);

        var δ = Number(distance) / radius; // angular distance in radians
        var θ = Number(bearing).toRad(); //this is line 50103

        var φ1 = Number(lat).toRad();
        var λ1 = Number(lng).toRad();

        var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(δ) +
            Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(δ)*Math.cos(θ) );
        var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(θ)*Math.sin(δ)*Math.cos(φ1),
                Math.cos(δ)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
        λ2 = (λ2+3*Math.PI) % (2*Math.PI) - Math.PI; // normalise to -180..+180°

        return {
            latitude: φ2.toDeg(),
            longitude: λ2.toDeg()
        };

    }
```

`
The bundle.js file was 80k lines so I don't know what to include of it. 
[image: Errors]

Comment: Without seeing the code, how are we supposed to know what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had explained it okay enough and there is a lot of code so I didn't know if I should put it all here. I'll edit the post to include.

Comment: Show the code around line 50103 of `bundle.js`.

Comment: @Barmar I have edited the post to include my code. Thanks for all your help

Comment: Do you really have backticks in the code. Those aren't needed in [so] code blocks.

Comment: When you click on the error location, does it point to which part of the line has the error?

Comment: No I don't have backticks in my actual code. My bundle.js doesn't show it has any errors in my IDE.

Comment: var Î´ = Number(distance) / radius; // angular distance in radians

Comment: that is the line it has an error with in browser, which is Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: If you click on the line number in the browser console it should take you to that line and put a squiggle or something under the error.

Comment: @Barmar I posted the line that has the error in a comment above

Comment: I see that. it's not the same one you mark in the code. But the browser might point to a specific place on the line.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong around that line.

Comment: Here is an image of the line in browser. With Browserify all you have to do is run "browserify main.js -o bundle.js" and then put the source in your html file, right? I can't understand why it isn't working. https://gyazo.com/21c2dbffca5191914439e8489659825b

Comment: Looks like an encoding problem. Notice that the variable names don't look like the Greek characters above.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for fixing the encoding?

Comment: Looks like this issue: https://github.com/browserify/browserify/issues/349

Comment: I just put charset="utf-8"  in the source and it is still putting the wrongly encoded characters in bundle. Hmmm

Comment: I manually changed the variables that encoded wrong but I still have these 2 errors. https://gyazo.com/e5be81de93b7b730191ccff0b98ab043 The loadmap() function is in bundle.js, so I'm unsure why it can't be reached

Comment: No idea now, sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If you can't figure it out I never will, haha. Goodbye to having good grades :)